# How to persist data in memory after closing popup extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, metamask, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm building a chrome extension, and I'd like to have some sensitive data stored in memory (not disk) while the user has their browser open. The data should persist in the chrome extension even if the user closes the extension popup and re-opens the popup.
How can I do this?

I believe this is possible because both Metamask and Bitwarden ask you for your password when you first open their extension after opening the browser. Then no matter how many times you close their extension and re-open it, the data persists, but I doubt that they are saving decrypted data to disk, so it must be kept in memory. I'd like to do the same, but whenever I try to save anything in the popup.html's JS file to memory, it never persists after closing the popup.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "TEST",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "TEST",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "./assets/images/icon16.png",
      "19": "./assets/images/icon19.png",
      "32": "./assets/images/icon32.png",
      "38": "./assets/images/icon38.png",
      "48": "./assets/images/icon48.png",
      "128": "./assets/images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "./assets/images/icon16.png",
    "19": "./assets/images/icon19.png",
    "32": "./assets/images/icon32.png",
    "38": "./assets/images/icon38.png",
    "48": "./assets/images/icon48.png",
    "128": "./assets/images/icon128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker-loader.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
```

Comment: In ManifestV3 you can use the in-memory API chrome.storage.session, which has the same methods as chrome.storage.local, but limited to 1MB overall.

Comment: @wOxxOm that works just great! I wish they had more documentation on it though, I couldn't find any. Do you know if Firefox has something similar? Also, if you submit this is an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: In FF you can simply store the data in the background script and access it via messaging, in other words just use MV2 paradigm. If you would post an answer with your actual code it'd be more helpful for posterity I think.